# How to resolve 'Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory' Exception after change of network?

Tags: java, mysql, struts2

I am developing a web-application with struts 2 and I am using gradle with the `tomcatRunWar`task.

Since I took my notebook home from work I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'vfsalesuser'@'192.168.2.110' 
(using password: YES))
```

Both, MYSQL-Server and the web-application run on the same machine. I didn't change anything of the applications-code or its config.

I also tried

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vfsalesuser'@'192.168.2.110';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Still doesn't work.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:** When I disable my main interface it works until I enable it again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the DHCP server from home and from work give you different IP/hostname addresses and you have hardcoded  somewhere in code/config the IP address received at work. Tomcat probably tries to open a socket on a non-existant IP hence the error.

You could try to search the configs for IP adresses or host name and change them into 127.0.0.1/localhost thus ensuring that always the sockets are opened on the local machine.

Some logs and configs would help here.

Comment: That was my first thought too. But I couldn't find any hardcoded IP-Adresses. Every config says localhost. Anyway, it should work if I allow the user to access the database from 192.168.2.110, which doesn't work in this case. I don't know why :/

Comment: Try the following: 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vfsalesuser'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vfsalesuser'@'127.0.0.1';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vfsalesuser'@'%';